# DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY") contains incorrect month

Tags: c#, excel, date, datetime, office-interop

So I have been adding a `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY")` to a List (along with a bunch of other data) and the later writing these lists to individual rows in an Excel workbook.

This all works great (it's something I do regularly), except, the month. I have tried exporting it three times and each time I get a different month;
the first time 56/26-17,
the second 2/26/2017,
and the third 14/26/2017....

Comment: It should be MM/dd/yyyy (lower case for days and years)

Comment: Please see [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for the proper codes.

Comment: it seems to me like you are using "mm" and not "MM" - "mm" is *minutes*, not months. However, that is guesswork since you haven't shown a small reproducable example

Comment: Exactly there is no [MCVE] and your single line of code cannot produce the errors above. Please add more context (more code) to your question

Comment: Considering "DD" and "YYYY" are invalid values, my guess is your code actually uses "mm/dd/yyyy" and there's something you aren't telling us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

"MM" for month. "dd" for days. "yyyy" for year.

"MM/DD/YYYY" is wrong format:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY")) // prints "06/DD/YYYY"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As already answered you need to have format specifier for day and year in small letters but as an add on you should also specify the culture variable to make sure that final output contains "/" between date parts. Without this culture parameter "/" could be replace by the date separator of the culture of system where code is running like "-".